# Errors occur when renaming and deleting resources in WSO2 Goverance Registry?

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

1. When i rename the collection name of entries in web ui, as an
   example, changing "test" to "TEST" it is getting failed. I had read the source code, why you judge by currentVersion, why you
   don't allow the user to rename ?
2. When i delete the collection , it is not getting deleteg from mysql
   database immediately. Is this a bug?

Comment: Can you please post the WSO2 Governance Registry version you are using and error logs occur when trying to rename the resource?

Comment: Please update your question by adding reproducing steps. these 2 questions are different modules. better to create separate question for each one of them. Please provide the greg version as well.

Answer (score 1):

## 1

I tried reproducing the issue by renaming a storage path of a soap-service. but no error was thrown.

[image]

## 2

No, it's not a bug. first, it will get deleted from the cache and then from the DB. In some cases, we keep the operation related record for audit purposes.

If you still think these are bugs please create [public jiras in here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/REGISTRY).